# Java specific substring

Tags: java, string, substring

I have strings of the following form:

```
1x Intel Celeron G1850*
```

How do i get a substring that only contains "Intel Celeron G1850"?
 - I am thinking about splitting between the x and the *

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you are thinking about?

Comment: I agree. Use the substring() method. There's nothing wrong with doing so.

Comment: The answer is in the question. Mark the question closed please.

Comment: I don't know how to do the  split? Furthermore, the name of the CPU between the x and * can be of variable lenght. Thats why i don't use a simple substring(start,end);

Comment: Check my answer for dealing with variable length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will deal with variable length of `1x`. I am assuming there are no `x` chars in the number of units for each record. I am also assuming the same format for each record

```
str.substring(str.indexOf('x') + 2);
```

This will pick up everything *including and after* the index location of `x` plus 2 indices which will place it on the first letter after the space.

`1x Intel Celeron G1850`

will result in

`Intel Celeron G1850`

This:

`1000x Intel Celeron G1850`

will result in the same

Answer (score 1):

Substring is a good option to consider. Not the split. Because of the complexity.

```
String str = "1x Intel Celeron G1850*";
str.substring(str.indexOf("x"), str.length() -1)
```

Comment: This answer does not work because of your own comment @CasperTL: the `1x` can be of variable length. What happens if this is `1000x` and you use index 3 as a constant? This answer is not universal

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it for this one (or very few) String(s), your approach is absolutely ok. The "mass wise" would be to compile a "RegExp" and match your (uniform and many) strings against it.

Like this:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d+x (.+)\\*$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1x Intel Celeron G1850*");
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you :) i can use the more simply answer by Faraj, but i'll def. look at this interesting method too :)